# Directive event to fire after HTML is appended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app I'm building that needs to convert XML to HTML on the fly, and then append it into a view. Since I don't have an XSLT file, I need to manually build each tag conversion to build a hunk of HTML that gets inserted into the view once this translation is done. Even then, because all nodes have not been identified or translated, I don't have a complete translation.

Furthermore, some of the XML nodes are being converted into Angular directives, to take advantage of expanding/collapsing. Therefore, I needed to go into `$compile`-land. Here is the directive I wound up creating:

```
angular.module('xxx').directive('xmlTransformer', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: link,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            content: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="xml-transformed"></div>'
    };

    function link(scope, element) {
        element.append($compile(scope.content)(scope));
    }
}
```

The content comes in from the parent view, since it controls what portion of the XML needs to be rendered (it's broken up into sections, so the view only brings back one section).

This works, very well, until I need to fire an event after the `element` has finished appending. This view *also* needs search capability and the user can come in from a global search page with a preset query. This is creating a timing issue where the search functionality is trying to find matches to data that hasn't been fully appended yet.

I've tried the following approaches to try to time this correctly:

1. Create an attribute directive that has `priority: 1001` and runs a method passed in.
2. Watch for when the master element has been appended and use `$timeout(fn, 0)` to ensure "the DOM has been completely rendered".

Neither approach work and the methods run before the content is finished appending. I was thinking of creating a `$q` promise so that after `element.append($compile(scope.content)(scope));` is run I have a callback, but I'm not sure that'll even work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create please jsfiddle with reproducible example.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko -- I'll try to get around to this later, there's a ton of tangential files that come into play here as well as proprietary XML that we're parsing so it would take a lot of work. So far I have it working on my Android device appending the content at the `compile` event and then using a callback on `link` with a timeout of 100ms. Thanks for your interest, I just need some time to get a sample uploaded without breaking any internal disclosures...with our sprint ending tomorrow! So I'm in cram mode now and might not be able to get to it until a day or so...